# Generating Code 128 Barcode for 300 Dpi Printer in ZPL Code

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, code128

I am trying to generate a Code 128 Barcode for a 300 Dpi Printer. When i try to scan the Barcode then at some points in the Barcode the Barcode is Scanable and at some points the barcode is not scanable and shows "Defect". Can someone please help.

When i scan the Barcode in the middle , then scanner shows "Defect" value > then allowed value

e.g allowed is 20% and the barcode at some points has 30 % or 40% which is greater then 20%.

Below is the code that is Use for barcode creation.

^XA
^MMT
^PW1240
^LL1724
^LS0
^CI28
^BY5,3,275^FT80,490^BCN,,Y,N,,A^FDABCDEF8K34694000267401^FS
^LRN
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ

Thanks

Need help with Correcting this Barcode to work with 300 Dpi wihtout any Defects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^XA ^MMT ^PW1216 ^LL1724 ^LS0 ^CI28 ^BY5,3,275^FT80,490^BCN,,Y,N,,A^FDABCDEF8K34694000267401^FS ^LRN ^PQ1,0,1,Y ^XZ
```

I think the 1240 is too large for 300dpi

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply . i tried it but the same results. There is still "defect" in the barcode. and the defect is 35%. this value should be less then 20%.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any workable 300 dpi C128 Barcode zpl code and if you can please provide it to me.so  that i can try with my 300 Dpi Printer. so that i can check if there is any problem with Barcode Printing with the Printer. Thanks

Comment: @user3337924 This is a good test site http://labelary.com/viewer.html  It might be that the label size needs different parameter values, I assumed you were on 6 by 4 inch label size but you might not be.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. but thats a 203 Dpi Code for 203 Dpi Printer

Comment: You can change those settings to 300dpi.  It's what I used for our warehouse scanners and bar codes.